# Background stops and i tried using repeat and anythign and everything i found

Tags: css, image, background

I am trying to create a website for a doctors office and I would like it to look as professional as possible but my background image (gradient image) will stop and wont repeat. I tried with `repeat-y`, `repeat-x` and left it alone so it does both repeats but nothing is working.

Code:

```
<div class="top">
    <body style="text-align: center; ">
    </body>
</div>
<div class="left">
    <p> Links </p>
    <section class="gradient">
        <button>sdf</button>
        <button>sdf</button>
        <button>sdf</button>
        <button>sdf</button>
        <button>sdf</button>
    </section>
sdfsdfs
<img src="file://../Images/Background.jpg" alt="Smiley face" height="42" width="42">
</div>
<div class="main">
    <style>
        img{
            position: absolute;
            margin: auto;
            top: 4000px;
            bottom: 1000px;;
            left: 0;
        }
        .top {
            position: absolute;
            left:0; right:0;
        }
        .left {
            background-image: url("file:/C:/Users/cody/Desktop/Website/Images/Background3.jpg");    
            position:absolute;
            left: 0; top: 300px; bottom: 0;
            width: 300px; height: auto;
        }
        .main {
            position: absolute;
            left:300px; top:300px; right:0; bottom:0;
        }
        .left {    
        }
        .main {
            background:    url("file:/C:/Users/cody/Desktop/Website/Images/Background.jpg");
        }
        section.gradient button {
            color: #fff;
            text-shadow: -2px 2px #0d4f99;
            background-color: #005fb3;
            background-image: linear-gradient(top, #0d5799, #0d4f99);
            box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px #13457d;
            border: none;
            border-radius: 8px;
        }
        section.gradient button:hover, section.gradient button.hover {
            box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px #13457d,0 5px 15px #152739;
        }

        section.gradient button:active, section.gradient button.active {
            box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px #13457d,inset 0 5px 30px #152739;
        }
        button {
            display: inline-block;
            margin: 1px 1px 1px 1px;
            padding: 5px 5px  5px 6px;
            font-size: 25px;
            font-family: "Bitter",serif;
            line-height: 0.8;
            appearance: none;
            box-shadow: none;
            border-radius: 0;
            height : 1.2em;
            width: 100%;
        }
        button:focus {
            outline: none
        }
        p.sansserif {
            padding-bottom: 30px;
            font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            font-size: 250%;
            color: black;
        }
    </style>
</div>
```

Also, I know I can put in a set height but I would rather have it change dynamically when I add an object.

Comment: I've never seen such kind of HTML structure!! you `body` is inside of a `div`!!

Answer (score 0):

The main thing that's important for background image repeating is to make sure that the `div` with the background-image css property is larger than the size of the background image itself. Did you check to see if that is true?

If your background-image url is sourcing a really large file (larger in pixels than the size of your div), then you can try setting the background-size property to be something smaller than the size of that div. I can't really tell the size of your image files based on the code provided, but maybe try that? Hope it helps.